# For builds and deploy we are using Jenkins, build and deploy taking long time at that time GCP token has expire. with that error JWT token issue

Tags: jenkins, groovy

For builds and deploy we are using Jenkins, build and deploy taking long time at that time GCP token has expire. with that error JWT token issue[JWT signature expired]with that falied message make it has condition and re run the Deploy job with manage our perameter

Comment: We have try and catch statment, it faling. if any other error also it was re triggring 
We have tested Naginator plugin, We are not able mange the Build perameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are getting the error, but simply have a condition in the `catch` block to check for the specific Error and then trigger the retry. Refer the following sample.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
    stage("A"){
        steps{
            script {
                retry(count: 3) {
                        try {
                            // Running stuff here
                            error "JWT signature expired"    
                        } catch(e){
                            echo "${e.getMessage()}"
                            if(e.getMessage().contains("JWT signature expired")) {
                                // Lets retry, by throwing an error
                                echo "Retrying!!!!"
                                error "Just retry"
                            }
                            echo "Not retrying!!!!"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```